# How to use git branches for project features?

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm working (alone) on a project that need several features to be added.
I'm used to create a branch for each feature. Once the feature is developed and well tested, I merge that branch-feature with the master branch.

Now, I started a feature (let's call it feature A) on `branch-A` that is not finished.
However, I urgently need to create a new feature B and push it before finishing feature A. That's why I created `branch-B` and switched to it.

However, running a `git status` command, I can see all the changed I made in the branch-A. I don't understand this default behaviour. I expected to see "no change" because they are different branches. I absolutely need that a commit in branch B ignores everything I dit in branch A.

What am I missing? How could I create the right workflow?

Comment: if you dont commit your changes in branch-A then those change will show in every branch, just commit those changes in branch-A & now you will not see those changes in any other branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't committed your changes into `branch-A` and switched to `branch-B`, so you received all this mess.

To avoid this behavior either commit your changes to `branch-A` permanently or [stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) them temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing the changes from `branch-A` because you have not committed them yet. Untracked changes are not removed when you switch between branches.

Do the following:

```
# Switch back to branch-A
git checkout branch-A

# Check the status
git status

# Add all of the changes
git add .

# Commit the changes
git commit -a

# Switch back to branch-B
git checkout branch-B

# Check git status
git status
```

If you want to commit your changes temporarily (and you don't want to use `git stash`), you could create a new branch off of `branch-A`:

```
# Switch back to branch-A
git checkout branch-A

# Create a new branch
git checkout -b branch-A-temp

# Add all of the changes
git add .

# Commit the changes
git commit -a

# Switch back to branch-B
git checkout branch-B

# Check git status
git status
```

You can go back to `branch-A-temp` later and continue to work on the changes. Once you're done, you can merge them into `branch-A`.

Learn to use branches liberally - they're lightweight and easy to use. If you want to try something, create a branch for it. They minimize the risk of losing changes, and you still have the full history, you can merge back and forth, etc. Branches are great for this kind of work.

Comment: Thanks for this. But let's say I made some terrible code that does not work in branch A. Should I commit it anyway?

Comment: Commit them for the time being (you could even create a new branch `branch-A-terrible` off of `branch-A` for it), and come back to it at a later point. Or stash your changes. I find branches easier to work with - stashing can become a mess if you keep multiple of them around.

Comment: try using command git checkout master and see with git status if you still have anything to commit

Answer (score 0):

I think you created a the new `branch B` while in `branch A`. This would create the `branch B` with the `branch A` as base. You must create `branch B` while in `master`. Or simply use this command

```
git checkout -b new-feature master
```